# Regex to allow up to two dots in email address

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate the first part of an email address and I want to allow up to two dots, for example these would be valid:

- alan@gmail.com
- alan.smith@gmail.com
- alan.smith.86@gmail.com

I have tried this regex pattern, but it's only matching one dot

`^([\w-]+[.-]?[']?[\w-]+)@([\w.-]+)$`

How could I change the pattern to allow for up to two dots?

Comment: You might try `^[\w'-]+(?:\.[\w'-]+){0,2}@[\w.-]+\.[\w-]+$`, but this pattern is too fragile.

Comment: Your regex leaves out a lot of potentially valid emails. Even if we take it as is, there is no actual limitation to have two dots. An email like "dr.john.e.smith.86@gmail.com" is perfectly valid. At any rate, back to the initial problem - don't try to block valid emails.

Comment: Further to VLAZ's comment, trust people to know their own email address - and use a verification email - to ensure validity.

Comment: Are you sure you want to keep `'` in an email-address ?

Comment: @Vulpo a name like "O'Hara" both exists in the real world *and* is valid within an email address. Why shouldn't `'` be kept in the email address?

Comment: The following website, https://regex101.com, will allow you to test and comprehend your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([\w\-]+\.?){0,2}[\w\-]+@[\w.\-]+$
```

The trick is to write "You can have a non-dotted characters before the `@`" (`[\w\-]+@`), but before that, you can have 0 to 2 times a dot-ended sequence: `([\w\-]+\.?){0,2}`

I suggest you to escape your `-`, as in some circumstances it is a special instruction.

If you want to save the group capture you suggested (Elvis operator `?:` prevents utility groups to be captured):

```
^((?:[\w\-]*\.?){0,2}[\w\-]+)@([\w.-]+)$
```